# Is it possible to create s3 event notification to two different Lambda Functions or two SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to create s3 event notification for the following cases:

- Lambda function: success or failure
- SQS: succeed or failed to upload

#### scenario and goal

The goal is the s3 bucket event notification triggers either SQS or Lambda functions, or even only SQS then its SQS will trigger one of Lambda functions or vise versa.

The flow would be

1. s3 upload object -> SQS or Lambda
2. s3 upload object -> ( SQS <-> Lambda )

I've tried using terraform code, however, I get this error below

> terraform apply
> (│ Error: creating S3 Bucket (aishoptest452) Notification: operation error S3: PutBucketNotificationConfiguration, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 4KC4VPWA3SVP9X9B, HostID: 1SmQtliWBJqgV115tiXaZWWTW2I4nST3tZo+E4lZU4hKZa4nTNx/ARx314tkgnJRh7+mRM/nrvI=, api error InvalidArgument: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.
> │
> │   with aws_s3_bucket_notification.bucket_notification,
> │   on main.tf line 100, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification":
> │  100: resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
> │)

This is my Terraform code:

```
# AWS provider configuration
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
        
# S3 bucket resource
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "aishoptest452"
}
        
# S3 bucket ownership controls
resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
      
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}
        
# S3 bucket ACL (Access Control List)
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "example" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.example]
        
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
  acl    = "private"
}
        
# SQS (Simple Queue Service) success queue resource
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "success_queue" {
  name                      = "success-queue"
  message_retention_seconds = 86400 # 1 day
}
        
# SQS failure queue resource
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "failure_queue" {
  name                      = "failure-queue"
  message_retention_seconds = 86400 # 1 day
}
        
# IAM Role for Lambda functions
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "lambda_execution_role"
        
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
     Version   = "2012-10-17"
     Statement = [{
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
     }]
  })
}

# IAM Policy for Lambda functions
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name        = "lambda_policy"
  description = "Policy for Lambda functions"
          
  policy = jsonencode({
            Version   = "2012-10-17"
            Statement = [{
              Effect    = "Allow"
              Action    = [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "sqs: SendMessage",
                "logs: CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs: PutLogEvents"
              ]
              Resource  = [
                aws_s3_bucket.example.arn,
                aws_sqs_queue.success_queue.arn,
                aws_sqs_queue.failure_queue.arn
          ]
      }]
  })
}
        
# Attach policy to role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_policy.arn
}
        
# Lambda function for success events
resource "aws_lambda_function" "success_lambda" {
  function_name    = "success_lambda_function"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  runtime          = "python3.8"  
  filename         = "${path.module}/lambda/success_lambda_function.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/lambda/success_lambda_function.zip")
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
}
        
# Lambda function for failure events
resource "aws_lambda_function" "failure_lambda" {
  function_name    = "failure_lambda_function"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  runtime          = "python3.8"  
  filename         = "${path.module}/lambda/failure_lambda_function.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/lambda/failure_lambda_function.zip")
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
}
        
# S3 bucket notification configuration
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
        
  # Lambda function notification for success events
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.success_lambda.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "uploads/success/"  # Unique prefix for success Lambda
  }
        
  # Lambda function notification for failure events
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.failure_lambda.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "uploads/failure/"  # Unique prefix for failure Lambda
  }
        
  # SQS queue notification for success events
  queue {
    queue_arn     = aws_sqs_queue.success_queue.arn
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
   filter_prefix = "uploads/success/"  # Unique prefix for success SQS
  }
        
  # SQS queue notification for failure events
  queue {
    queue_arn     = aws_sqs_queue.failure_queue.arn
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix = "uploads/failure/"  # Unique prefix for failure SQS
  }
}
        
# Output values
output "bucket_name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
}
        
output "success_queue_url" {
  value = aws_sqs_queue.success_queue.id
}
        
output "failure_queue_url" {
  value = aws_sqs_queue.failure_queue.id
}
```

Comment: You can configure S3 event notification for triggering 2 different lambda functions or 2 sqs or more AWS resources with event types. Please post your terraform code so people can help

Comment: Where's the terraform code that doesn't work? How are we supposed to fix it without seeing it?

Comment: Hi, I have added my Terraform code, please see my edited question above. thanks.

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty straightforward: `Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.`. I would guess it means you cannot use the same prefixes in both Lambda and SQS notification for the same event.

Comment: @MarkoE it's not straightforward enough if you have to guess :)

Comment: From the code what I am trying to archive is set up s3 event notification for 2 sqs one for success upon upload and one for failure upon upload, I'm not sure how to go about that without running into that error, your assistant will be highly appreciated

Comment: @gshpychka I just wanted to say it might be easier to find the answer elsewhere, e.g, https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-s3-event-configuration-error.